# save dataframe as external hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have used one way to save dataframe as external table using parquet file format but is there some other way to save dataframes directly as external table in hive like we have saveAsTable for managed table

Answer (score 5):

you can do this in this way

df.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path"-> "yourpath")) saveAsTable "anubhav"

Comment: Is this the PySpark way?

Comment: Works! but needs little correction. It should be df.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path"-> "yourpath")).saveAsTable ("anubhav") :)

Answer (score 4):

In **PySpark**, External Table can be created as below:

```
df.write.option('path','<External Table Path>').saveAsTable('<Table Name>')
```

Comment: I don't think it created a 'external table', actually it creates a managed table with external path.  You can check with 'show create table '

Answer (score 3):

For external table, don't use `saveAsTable`. Instead, save the data at location of the external table specified by `path`. Then add partition so that it is registered with hive metadata. This will allow you to hive query by partition later.

`// hc is HiveContext, df is DataFrame.
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path)
val sql =
      s"""
         |alter table $targetTable
         |add if not exists partition
         |(year=$year,month=$month)
         |location "$path"
       """.stripMargin
hc.sql(sql)`

Comment: i in the past used to use above approach. but one can certainly eg. in spark 2 or 3, use save as table: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Answer (score -2):

You can also save dataframe with manual create table

```
dataframe.registerTempTable("temp_table");
hiveSqlContext.sql("create external table 
   table_name if not exist as select * from temp_table");
```

Below mentioned link has a good explanation for create table  https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html

Comment: Wrong. You cannot create an external table without a 'location'